# Might biking lower forehead temp readings at destination?

Tags: commuter, health, bike-vs-car, coolweather

I often bike to work at a place that screens all who enter for fever. Lately this has been done with a no-touch forehead thing, presumably an IR gadget. When I bike, even if it is cold enough that I wish I'd worn full-finger gloves, the final uphill makes me sweat, yet even so I consistently arrive with my forehead so cool that the gadget gives a number in the 92° Fahrenheit (33°C) range, or more often just refuses to give any number at all. When I make the trip by car, by contrast, it consistently gives more normal readings of 94.7° fahrenheit (35°C)

As a 65-year-old male on a beta blocker, I expect my body to run a little cooler than average, but 92°F (33°C)  or lower for a forehead reading seems extreme. It's as if the biking itself is somehow an additional cooling factor. Could this be? Have others found this, now that "temping in" is grown so common?

I get that evaporative cooling with sweat is peculiarly effective for the cyclist, thanks to the air flow, and that the forehead is a prime site for it; but it hardly seems like that should make the forehead peculiarly cool, since (with apologies to Shakespeare) the blood is hot that must be cooled by this. (By analogy, the fins on a motorcycle engine also exploit air flow for cooling; but one hardly expects them to be cool to the touch after a long uphill has put their cooling capacity to the test.)

Comment: Do I understand that you do not wear a helmet or a hat-cap? This never happens to me, my head is always very sweaty. I need to wear a scarf under my helmet to avoid loads of drip. And it certainly does not feel cold.

Comment: I don't know enough to write a full answer but I wanted to say that I had a similar experience biking somewhere recently on a cold-ish day while biking with a helmet. I didn't "feel cold" but the temperature that the forehead thing read was really cold

Comment: I assume that it is similar to how some of the thermometers that go in your mouth give strange readings if you just drank water or another cold beverage (I assume something similar is true for hot beverages too but I've never tried)

Comment: I'm interested too - I used a general purpose IR thermometer rather than a medical one, but after a hot ride on a hot day, wearing a helmet, I was surprised to see it cooler than just sitting around at home. It's presumably to do with the depth that emits IR of the relevant wavelength, compared to the depth debate the nerve endings are that sense heat (in itself an oversimplification). Probably the thermometer reads the very surface, which is effectively cooled by sweat, but the sensation of heat is deeper. Probably.

Comment: @GageMartin not really. A cold drink makes your mouth colder for a while, and an oral thermometer is in contact with that - it's not surprising that they read cooler than typical body temperature. The non contact forehead thermometers use infra-red emitted by the  person being tested, and appear at first glance to go in the opposite direction to what's expected

Comment: @VladimirF, on the contrary, I do wear a helmet. As I always say: if you don't think your brain is worth protecting, you're probably right.

Comment: I would say that you should wait at least 15 minutes, after cycling, to check temp.  A number of different factors are at work.

Comment: if sweat is actively evaporating from your forehead, i would expect the IR thermometer to read lower.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The wacky readings do not get me stopped or otherwise inconvenienced, & that would mean leaving home & wife for work that much earlier. I was just curious, but maybe not *that* curious.

Comment: This is precisely what the receptionist at my dentist's office said when I cautioned that I'd arrived via the well known "bike trail" (left out the "on a unicycle" part) and was worried I might initially read high; she claimed that they'd seen people typically read low.  While "the plural of anecdote is not data", given the character of the town and the office location at the junction of three great rail trails connecting many of its neighbourhoods I don't doubt that patients riding to appointments happened fairly frequently.

Comment: Don't temperatures in that range imply it may not be working at all?

Comment: Can you aim the sensor into your open mouth and get a more-useful reading that way ?   Hold your breath for the duration, to stop condensation on the lenses.

Comment: @VladimirF If you have sweat dripping down from your face, you are either living in a brutal climate (= humid hot), or you are wearing too much clothes. It's a common mistake that I see over and over again when I ride through my own city in winter: When I still ride in T-shirt, most people I see on bikes are already in thick, warm jackets. I would be melting away if I did this. But the truth is, when temperatures get cold, you are either cold on the first kilometers, or you are hot at the end of your tour. People tend to dress to be comfortable on the first meters, but suffer in the long run.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Seems you are lucky and have hair on the top of your head. Just wait until you get bald. At least partially. You will find you can't go for a run without at least headband (better a scarf for UV protection). I mostly cycle in a short jersey and short bib shorts FYI. I tend to protect my knees from cold, though.

Comment: The truth is that we do not have an IR body thermometer in the office, only a FLIR camera, so I never tried to measure my head tempersture.  So now after hearing from more people here I do believe their reports. But waiting for several minutes might reverse it because I remember feeling still quite hot, even on my head when going for a shower, or indeed even after having a shower.

Comment: @VladimirF Why? My head will be less exposed than my arms. There's still a helmet on top of it, after all. Being bald, winter would call for a thin cap beneath the helmet, but against the sun, sunscreen does a fantastic job.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica Helmets I have or tested do not stop the drip. There is too  little material in contact with the bald head. My skin doctor explicitly forbade me from exposing my head to the sun and required me to use sunscreen factor 50 when it is necessary. So I also wear a swimming cap.

Comment: @VladimirF But helmets don't start dripping unless your body is overheating. Again, either from hot humid weather, or from a lack of cooling from other parts of the body. If you expose enough skin to the slipwind, your body can control its temperature without producing sweat that does not evaporate quickly. Unless you are riding in humid heat, that is.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica That is just nonsense, first get bald, then lecture please. Thin sportswear actually helps evaporation, but really, I don't everdress. Not even close. I get loads of drip without a cap even when cross-country skiing at -5C in light clothes in which you can't stop.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica you forgot riding hard in that list of options - anything above freezing, dressed for decency with a helmet, 16% climb -> lots of sweat; the sweatband in the helmet saturates easily

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, I forgot about real mountains. Sorry. I just don't have any around here XD

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica just steep hills round here, but no shortage of them

Comment: Remember - answers go in answers, where comments are for clarifications and improvements.

Comment: We use an IR thermometer and I ride to work and often arrive with a sweaty forehead. The reading are usually the low side of normal. One of my coworkers who drives to work and isn't sweaty at all often won't even register. Short answer is a damp forehead does not impact the reading.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The body controls its core temperature, not the skin temperature. Skin temperatures will vary significantly, to the point they are generally considered an unreliable way to measure core temperature, especially for people under heat stress (Riding a bicycle).  (Refer : [here](https://www.cebm.net/2020/08/screening-for-covid-19-with-infrared-thermometers-more-marketing-than-medical-evidence/))

Screening using such a thermometer is more about the "Security theater" of being seen to do something, but the high incidence of false positives and false negatives make the concept unreliable and falling into the realm of "Theater". ([Here](https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2020/08/paging-dr-hamblin-temperature-checks-coronavirus/615190/))

Comment: I have an IR thermometer with 3 emissivity settings. The readings differs by 1°C from setting to setting. So much for precision.

Comment: Readings from a non-contact IR thermometers are generally well-correlated with other temperature measurements, although they do tend to be a bit lower, and there are a few things that can screw up the reading. But still, studies have shown that they can detect fevers with high sensitivity/specificity. Where this becomes security theater is not in the IRT's ability to detect a fever, but whether the fever is diagnostic of COVID. Regardless of how temperature is measured (even if done perfectly), temperature checks are still not sufficiently sensitive/specific to be a good screen for COVID.

Comment: IR thermometers can be used in controlled conditions - indoors with sedentary patients to infer core temperature based on experimental observations made of the last decades.  Using an IR thermometer in field conditions came from the Military need to quickly identify the living from the dead. The Covid response to deploy these has combined the two use cases with little science to back it up.  Its theater that gets lucky very occasionally with little concern for the many negative side effects of its deployment.

Comment: This is merely anecdotal, but I find that if you point an IR thermometer at the inside of someone's mouth, you get very accurate and consistent readings.  Whether this is sanitary or not is a different issue altogether.

Comment: @NuclearWang So the IR thermometer can measure core temperatures and not just surface temps? How is that supposed to work? Obviously core and surface temps can be in sync under given circumstances but "person straight from street" is not one of those I'd think.

Answer (score 9):

One factor could be the lower emissivity of sweat compared to human skin. At a given temperature, different materials emit different amounts of infrared radiation for the thermometer to detect. Skin has an emissivity of about 0.97. (1.0 is the maximum possible value). At the same temperature, pure water will emit slightly less because it has 0.96 emissivity. Sweat might emit even less than water because of the salt and everything else mixed in. Hospitals need to reconfigure IR thermometers if a patient's skin has ultrasound gel, disinfectant, etc... because all of those things change the skin's emissivity. I wouldn't count on the IR thermometer at the front door being smart enough to automatically configure its emissivity setting when pointed at a sweaty face.

IR thermometers are used because they are fast and contactless. They are accurate when measuring *external* temperature and the material's emissivity is known and constant. But in the scenario described in the question, there are too many factors at play for an IR thermometer to reliably detect fever in every person.

If you JUST stepped off your bike after a ride in the cold, I doubt it's possible for an IR thermometer to grab a useful reading on your internal temperature no matter where they point it.

Comment: How do they compensate for different body parts having different surface temperature?

Comment: @ojs There is no reason to compensate for that, that is what you are trying to measure.

Comment: You are certainly meaning that it has an emissivity of 97 %, not a reflectance of 97 %. With a reflectance of 97 % the measurement wouldn't work out at all.

Comment: @Arsenal Right, totally mix up the verbiage in my head. Updating answer...

Answer (score 6):

Due to Covid I have to measure my body temperature when I enter the office. Since I happen to bike to work, I was concerned my temperature would be measured to be "hot".

Well, it turned out that in the morning, even though I am sweaty from a 40 minutes ride, my forehead barely reaches 29 Celsius, regardless if I am cycling bare head or wearing a head cover.

Don't underestimate the cooling effect on extremities.

Comment: And, do they sent you to ER urgently to be treated for severe hypothermia? :-)

Comment: @gerrit, I am glad they are after covid symptoms and not zombie apocalypse's one :D

Comment: I too measure my temperature after cycling to work. Short ride, just over 5 minutes. Yet my temperature is usually measured as "Lo", i.e < 34 C. A guy behind me in the queue (who I assume drove to work) measured 36.5, so the thermometer isn't broken.